# Elasticsearch bulk delete causes "Courier Fetch" error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trouble-shooting a logstash bulk import configuration file.  Therefore, I'm repeatedly deleting and reloading data into ElasticSearch (via Logstash).

To bulk delete the data, I'm using:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/nbu_job'
```

After doing that, I get errors (in Kibana) similar to this:

```
Courier Fetch: 133 of 160 shards failed
```

Is there any way for me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You may check your cluster templates, go to settings and reload the field list of your index. Maybe you have some missing templates in you cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I went to Kibana, then "Settings" tab, then clicked on my index (logstash-*).  Then clicked on the orange button (reload field list).  Is that what you meant ?  After doing that, went to my Kibana dashboard, and refreshed it.   Still getting the "Courier Fetch" error.    Any other things I could try ?

Comment: Yes, I had this problem before and It worked after I did "reload Field list" in "logstash-*" under index patterns.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to fix my problem.